# custom hook create infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render

This hook create an inifite loop. I don't understnd why, since my dependencies array is set.

Error : `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`

Custom hook :

```
export const useListGuessers = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);

    const hasMarketing = UserHelper.hasAuthorization(AUTHORIZATION_MARKETING);
    const hasTechnical = UserHelper.hasAuthorization(AUTHORIZATION_TECHNICAL);

    const dashboardGroups = new DashboardGroups({hasMarketing, hasTechnical});

    const guessers = [
        ...dashboardGroups.appProductGroup(),
        ...dashboardGroups.articlesGroup(),
        ...dashboardGroups.mediasGroup(),
        ...dashboardGroups.productsGroup(),
        ...dashboardGroups.orderableProductsGroup(),
        ...dashboardGroups.typesGroup(),
        ...dashboardGroups.usersGroup(),
        ...dashboardGroups.othersGroup(),
        ...dashboardGroups.userManagementGroup(),
    ];

    const filteredGuesser = guessers
        .filter(({canShow}) => canShow)
        .map((guesser: any) => {
            return {
                label: guesser.label ?? guesser.value.options.label,
                link: (guesser.operation && `user-management/${guesser.operation}`) ?? guesser.value.name,
            };
        })
        .sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label));

    useEffect(() => {
        filteredGuesser && setList(filteredGuesser);
    }, [filteredGuesser]);

    return list;
};
```

The class :

```
export class DashboardGroups {
    authorizations: {hasMarketing: boolean; hasTechnical: boolean};

    constructor(authorizations: {hasMarketing: boolean; hasTechnical: boolean}) {
        this.authorizations = authorizations;
    }

    // [all groups comes here...]

    getGroups = () => {
        // return an object for each groups with labels, and the group as "children"
    };
}
```

Comment: Probably because you're creating a new `DashboardGroups` on every render, so `filteredGuesser` changes on every render as well, triggering a new rerender and so on... I'm curious, why are you using class components + hooks?

Comment: Work restrictions. I have to adapt my React code on existing classes. Thank you for your suggestion, going to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `filteredGuesser` calculates on each re-render, which triggers `useEffect(..., [filterGuesser]` which causes re-render... so it loops.

The easiest straighforward solution is to ensure reference equality for `filteredGuesser` with `useMemo`. Then it will be referentially the same until `guessers` is changed:

```
const filteredGuesser = useMemo(() => 
  guessers
    .filter(({canShow}) => canShow)
    .map((guesser: any) => {
      label: guesser.label ?? guesser.value.options.label,
      link: (guesser.operation && `user-management/${guesser.operation}`) ?? guesser.value.name,
     })
     .sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label))
, [guessers]);
```

However, I think the better solution would be reconsider need in

```
useEffect(() => 
...
 setList(filteredGuesser)
```

This storing ready for use calculation into state does not seem reasonable to me. I think you better use `filteredGuesser` directly, instead of storing it into `list` state

[Beta docs for `useMemo`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo)

[Referential equality aka strict equality on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: VEry great idea to return filteredGuessers. Thank you very much ! Been strugling for hours !